# `change:center` event not fired on drag animation

Tags: openlayers, events

I'm quite new in OpenLayers, and I want to act when the map is moved.

So simply listening to the `change:center` event of the map's view:

```
map.getView().on('change:center', function(evt){
   console.log(map.getView().getCenter());
}
```

But I've noticed the event is not fired after we finish the map panning with the mouse - and the map is still moving and slowing down until it stops completely.

Is there another way to know when the map extent is changed?

Answer (score 1):

The moveend event on the Map instance should do what you need: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.MapEvent.html?unstable=true#event:moveend

Comment: :D Don't know how i missed this. After checking it out, it fired only in the end of the change. So i almost covered all cases. While the map panning i have the `changed:center` of the view. But there is animation between the mouse up till the end of the animation that i don't get trough those events.

Comment: Ok, found some workaround. I am listening to the view's `change:center` event. and to the `moveend` of the map's. in the center change event i'm start listening to the map's `postrender` event (only once) and in the `moveend` i'm stop listening to it. This way i'm getting the map real location at all times.